# Bootstrap 3.0 row and image/div side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to accomplish this with bootstraps' grid system ( I may be misusing it ).

What I want is a div wherein the left most edge is an image, and the remaining content is a full sized .row to house form fields.  I think I'm missing something fundamental about how bootstrap uses it's various classes.

```
<div class="card">
  <span class="f-icon glyphicon glyphicon-file pull-left"></span>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    I want this to be the first half of the remaining content
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    I want this to be the second half of the remaining content
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p37bc1n0/

Comment: oops wrong fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p37bc1n0/1/

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/p37bc1n0/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker this would work if I could rely on the size of the icon to be determined by a col div.  What I'm trying to drive at is to just have the row next-to a static image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just apply `display: flex` to `.card` and the text cells will occupy 50% of the remaining width since the col classes have `width: 50%`. If you wanted to split that remaining width the "flex" way, you can remove the col classes from the text divs, and assign `flex: 1 0 0;` to them so they will grow to fill the remaining space evenly.

```js
$("#edit-uploads-modal").show();
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px #888888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f7f7f7, #fff);
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.card > div { flex: 1 0 0; }

.f-icon {
  font-size: 6em;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.modal-style {
  width:900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id="edit-uploads" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-uploads-modal">Edit Uploads</button>

<div id="edit-uploads-modal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-style" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Uploads</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="card">
          <span class="f-icon glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
          <div>
            I want this to be the first half of the remaining content
          </div>
          <div>
            I want this to be the second half of the remaining content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="update" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
        <button id="save-files" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save And Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In a perfect world this would be the accepted answer - however I have this lead weight named IE-9 tied around my ankle.  For anyone else who is looking for a modern solution to this problem - look no further than the native display: flex css property

Comment: Wow I just wrote out basically the same answer. OP [here is my link to my jsfiddle but it also uses this flexbox method](https://jsfiddle.net/p37bc1n0/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Check the below jsfiddle. You need 3 column layout: One to keep img, second to keep first half of the content and third to keep second half of the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/Smita31Jain/ctm7juLj/

```
 <div class="card">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
     <span class="f-icon glyphicon glyphicon-file pull-left"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
     I want this to be the first half of the remaining content
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
     I want this to be the second half of the remaining content
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: similar to Michael's solution above - I'm really looking for a solution where the image does not need to be a part of the row - period.  I'd like to be able to make full use of the 6/6 columns on the right and maintain the dimensions of the image separately - otherwise it feels like a waste of screen real estate

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Smita31Jain/ctm7juLj/. See if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Smita - It's interesting that pulling the icon left produces a different result than pulling the row right - and it still bothers me that I can't easily reduce the space between the row & icon - but this is the best solution so far!